# Slutsky theorem

Tags: probability, probability-theory

I am trying to understand how to apply Slutsky's theorem. Say we focus on $X_n\longrightarrow\mathcal{N}$ the standard normal, in distribution and $Y_n\longrightarrow 0$ a.s. The theorem says that $X_n+Y_n\longrightarrow \mathcal{N}$ in distribution. So for example $\mathbb{P}(X_n+Y_n<0)\longrightarrow \Phi(0)$ ($\Phi$ is the cdf of $\mathcal{N}$). I would like to know if the theorem applies to the following scenario: we have a sequence of events, $E_n=(X_n+Y_n<0)\cap(Y_n\longrightarrow 0)$. $X_n$ as before, but this time, $Y_n$ is such that $0<\mathbb{P}(Y_n\longrightarrow 0)<1$. So we can see that $Y_n$ does not vanish almost surely on the probability space, but it does so on $E_n$. Can one, by using $\mathbb{P}(E_n)=\mathbb{P}(X_n+Y_n<0|Y_n\longrightarrow 0)\mathbb{P}(Y_n\longrightarrow 0)$, conclude similarly by Slutsky theorem that $\mathbb{P}(E_n)\longrightarrow \Phi(0)\mathbb{P}(Y_n\longrightarrow 0)$? In other words, does the theorem applies when conditioning is involved?

Comment: what event is $(Y_n\longrightarrow 0)$?

Comment: it is an event i just defined and assumed non negligible nor almost sure, you can call it $A=(Y_n\longrightarrow 0)$. Then $E_n=(X_n+Y_n<0)\cap A$.